# My printing method is returning null values

Tags: java, arrays, class, printing

So i created a class with the add and print methods for a list containing that class attributes, but once i run them on the program class, when i print them it returns null values to me, can someone help me out?

```
package entidades;
import java.util.*;

public class Profissional extends UnidadeSaude {
    private String categoriaP;
    private String nomeP;


    public Profissional(String nomeUnidade,String categoriaP, String nomeP) {
        super(nomeUnidade);
        this.categoriaP = categoriaP;
        this.nomeP = nomeP;     
    }   
    public Profissional() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Profissional(String categoriaP2, String nomeP2) {

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profissional [categoriaP=" + categoriaP + ", nomeP=" + nomeP + "]";
    } 
    public String getcategoriaP() {
        return categoriaP;
    }
    public void setcategoriaP(String categoriaP) {
        this.categoriaP = categoriaP;
    }
    public String getnomeP() {
        return nomeP;
    }
    public void setnomeP(String nomeP) {
        this.nomeP = nomeP;
    }
    public void RegistarProfissional(List<Profissional>rProfissional, String categoriaP,String nomeP) {
        rProfissional.add(new Profissional(categoriaP, nomeP));
    }
    public void ListarProfssional(List<Profissional>rProfissional) {
            System.out.println(rProfissional);
        }

    }
```

The Program code is this:
 [Program code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhuHQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `RegistarProfissional`, you are creating a new `Professional` and using the `Profissional(String categoriaP2, String nomeP2)` constructor to do it (by passing in the 2 constructor parameters of `categoriaP, nomeP`. The problem is that the constructor you are using to create the `Professional` doesn't set the fields that you are then printing.

To fix the issue you should update your constructor:

```
public Profissional(String categoriaP2, String nomeP2) {
    this.categoriaP = categoriaP2;
    this.nomeP = nomeP2; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically i had set values im my two-args constructor, otherwise they stayed null like alea sayed.
It is now working, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have no values set in your two-args constructor. You should set these values in any way, otherwise they will stay null.

```
public Profissional(String categoriaP2, String nomeP2) {
    this(null, categoriaP2, nomeP2);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong constructor in your RegistarProfissional method. Change the construcktors like that and it will work.

```
public Profissional(String nomeUnidade,String categoriaP, String nomeP) {
    super(nomeUnidade);
    this.categoriaP = categoriaP;
    this.nomeP = nomeP;     
}   
public Profissional() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Profissional(String categoriaP2, String nomeP2) {
    super(null);
    this.categoriaP = categoriaP;
    this.nomeP = nomeP;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The constructor that you used in "RegisterProfessional" is empty. So the values.

```
public Profissional(String categoriaP2, String nomeP2) {
   this(null, categoriaP2, nomeP2);
}
```